# php - how to sort array by keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have itinerary/tour page that contain number of sections: header. description, body, guide_details, footer

I would like to let my client to set the order - which section will appear first, second, third...

So I have array from DB that contain the number of each section. The number id the section position

Table itin_oreder:

```
clientID     header    description  body  guide_details footer
   6           1            3        2          4          5

$query = "SELECT * FROM itin_oreder WHERE client= 6 ";
$res = mysql_query($query);
```

I also have array that contain the content of each section:

```
itinContent = array ("header" => $header, "description" => $description....)
```

How do I print the array itinContent in the order that the client set?

Comment: haven't you tried `asort`, or just simply google `sort arrays php`?

Comment: `mysql_query()` -- what is that? Have you read its [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)? There is a big red warning that says ***"This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used"***.

Comment: You need to create a `form` so the client can use that to sort the query, or use DataTables and they can sort it them self with a click of a button.

Comment: @axiac - `mysql_query()` is the code to run sql queries and it's working on PHP 5.1 - the same the one i use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for call "uksort" ([uksort  in PHP-MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php))

Let say you have itin_oreder array with the order to the scheme. you can build comparison  function by that global array.

This is sample code:

```
<?php

$init_order= array("clientID"=>6, "header"=>3, ...);
$initContent = array ("header" => $header, "description" => $description....)

function sortByInitOrder($a,$b)
{
        global $init_order;
        return ($init_order[$a] > $init_order[$b]);
}

uksort($initContent, 'sortByInitOrder');
echo print_r($initContent, true);
```

If you want to print only the array values:

```
foreach($initContent as $key => $value)
{
  echo "$value \n";
}
```

Comment: Hi David, i read about uksort but dodn't understand how its should works and how to use it...can you please explain?

Comment: uksort is a PHP function that sort the given array by user-define function that operate on the array keys. As you can see in my example, I define the compare function according to the init_order array - taking the client order and rearrange the key of the initContent array accordingly. Did you try to run the example? (after setting you array)

Comment: Thanks. Not yet, but i'm about to...

Comment: David, you code also print the $initContent  key name (i.e: "header") how can i not print it?

Comment: Do you want to print only the value without the key? why?

Comment: Because i only need to print the body and description on the screen. I don't need to print the words ` Array ( [description] => ` or ` [body] => `

Comment: ok, i used foreach loop and fix it. thanks!

Comment: Done. Hope i did it right....